# Formal way to phrase "as my background tells"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am currently writing a cover letter and I wanted to say "As my (work and education) background tells, I am tech savvy."

However, I feel like the phrase "As my background tells" is a bit awkward and need an advice as to how to amend this phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write:

> As my background **states**,  I am tech savvy.

referring to the previous *statements* about your background.

If you really want to use *tell*, then you could write:

> As my background tells *you*, I am tech savvy.

but that would be too direct for a cover letter or resume, as it has a more "I told you so" implication.

Comment: I would suggest that *backgrounds* do not **state** or **tell** things, even when referring back. It's an awkward construction that you could avoid by saying something like: **As you may tell/infer/conclude from my background.....**.

Comment: @RonaldSole agreed.  Your resume / CV can *state* a lot of things about your skill set, because that's an actual document.